# How to Pass a User object as parameter to node.js's Express api like asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js

I am learning node.js, i need to pass a User object to node.js's Express api, i have seen few documents for my question, but its all about **bodyparser**. but i need to know is bodyparser only the good solution for this problem, or i can send the User object as **Object Type Data Type** which .Net/Java do. i need to send the object exactly like given .net example.

**User Object**

```
var user={
    "Id":1,
    "FullName":"Mr. X"
}
```

**ASP.NET Method**
if i send the above user via ajax its automatically fit with my asp.net method's parameter(User u).

```
public IHttpActionResult Save(User u)
{
    return Ok(_userService.Save(u));
}
```

**Node.Js**

```
var req=require('body-parser');
router.post('/save', function (req, res) {
    var user=req.body.User;
    return userServices.Save(user).then(function (results) {
        res.send(results);
    }).catch(function (reason) {
        res.send(reason);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's pronounced "you-zer" not "ooze-er", so it should be "a User", not "an User"...

Comment: Thanks @musefan, edited .

Comment: it's quite unclear what exactly the problem is... are you saying that your node.js code isn't working when you pass the object (as defined in first example)? Do you have a specific error? Or can you describe what is actually happening that isn't correct? It might help to show exactly what you are trying to assign to `param`

Comment: i don't have any error, i need to know what is the best approach to pass an object (user) to node.js . Thanks

Comment: Well if it is working, then that one seems pretty fine to me. You sound like you are trying to anticipate a future problem that may never even happen, what about this method do you not like?

Comment: i have edited the problem, please see again the node.js code, is bodyparser is ok/ any other good solution?

Comment: You should use "post" instead of "get" .

Comment: mistakenly get initiated. see again, but this is not the solution.

Comment: If you look at the ASP, and the Node.js, there essentially doing the same.  If you like the ASP one liner, you can just create a function called Ok that does the same thing.

Comment: @Keith my focus about the user parameter, not the method's implementation. Thanks !

Comment: @sebu, you can create it so the parameters are like that.. it's pretty flexible is JS..  I can show you a snippet if that's what your interested in.

Comment: ok @Keith, please post your snippet

Answer (score 1):

Ok, using your above example.

Let's assume we have JSON post request ->

```
{
    "Id":1,
    "FullName":"Mr. X"
}
```

Instead of having all the boiler code for error handling etc, with JS you can create a wrapper function to handle this.  Seen as your using promises this is even better.

So what were after is something like ->

```
router.post('/save', handlePost((user) => userServices.Save(user)) );
```

To me, that looks pretty much similiar to the ASP version, and in fact is doing more as it's actually showing the route `/save`, that you didn't show in the ASP version.

So the next stage is creating the  `handlePost` function..

```
function handlePost(func) {
  return (req, res) => {
    func(req.body).then((results) => {
      res.send(results);
    }).catch((reason) => {
      res.status(500).send(reason);
    });    
  }
}
```

Hopefully this is what you was after.

The handlePost, of course can be re-used for all your requests if using promises, in fact not just Post requests, so I really should have named it `handleReq`,. or even `ok` like ASP did.

Comment: Then `userServices.Save` is not returning a promise.